# UI5 web application deployed by cloudformation, how to create SSM parameters so they can be accessible later?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sapui5, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I have a UI5 web application which has no access to AWS Parameter store. However, it is deployed by CloudFormation, by an account which has this access - I already collect some values from SSM during deployment and use them as parameters for resources which are being deployed by template.yml file.

However, now I need some of these parameters not only during deployment, but also during actual run of the app. Does someone familiar with AWS and UI5 know, how can I store these values during deployment so I can use them later, during the run of the web application? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the CloudFormation template then you can add resources of type [`AWS:SSM:Parameter`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html) to the template which will create SSM Parameters as part of the deployment.

Example:

```
Resources:
  BasicParameter:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: /my/basic/parameter
      Type: String
      Value: my-basic-parameter-value
      Description: A description of the parameter
```